# Те () самые настоящие пончики - нужна ли на месте скобок запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая на месте скобок?

Comment: Без знания контекста однозначно ответить на поставленный вопрос невозможно. Возможны варианты, в т. ч. и вариант с запятой после слова "самые".

Answer (score 1):

***Те самые настоящие пончики...***

1) После ***те*** запятая не ставится: *тот самый, те самые* — это **единое сочетание**, что видно из словаря:

**САМЫЙ,**  местоим. прил. 1. (при указат. и личн. местоим.). Употр. при уточнении; именно, как раз. **Эта самая** книга. В **этом самом** месте. В **эту самую** минуту. **Тот самый** человек.

НАСТОЯЩИЙ, 3. Подлинный, истинный; натуральный. Н. кофе. Н-ее золото.

2) Вариант ***те самые, настоящие пончики*** в принципе возможен, здесь отношения между определениями однородные (те самые пончики, настоящие пончики), но практически он если и используется, то редко.

3) Указательные местоимения, **как правило,** считаются **неоднородными** по отношению ко второму определению (запятой нет).

Примеры:

*Посреди зала сидел **тот самый пряничный старик** с рынка, хозяин курицы.*

*На столе  стоял **тот самый знаменитый украинский борщ**.*

*И тут Владик увидел **тот самый огромный джип**, лихо въезжающий и паркующийся неподалеку.*

4) Но:  *Наконец возник голубой забор, **тот самый, истинный**.* В постпозиции определения становятся однородными.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. У нас есть только указательное местоимение-прилагательное "тот" (те) перед местоимением-прилагательным "самый" (самые).

Если бы предложение имело продолжение, пригодилось бы нижеследующее правило.

[Розенталь, § 18, п. 4:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)

> Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного
>   или притяжательного местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не
>   отделяется:
>
> *Эти недавно опубликованные стихи были написаны много лет назад.*